# Is common_schema safe?

Tags: digital-signature, mysql, confidentiality

**Edit**: this already has an answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155355/is-common-schema-safe).

I just ran across [common_schema](https://code.google.com/archive/p/common-schema/), a utility for MySQL database administrators. It is a SQL script that creates a schema called common_schema in your database and plenty of stored procedures.

I need it for a corporate database that stores confidential information. How can I make sure it is safe? It is stored on Google Code and doesn't have a checksum or even less a signature. I'm just supposed to do some

```
mysql -u root -p < common_schema-2.2.sql
```

But somehow it doesn't feel right to dump 31K SQL lines into my DB. Am I missing something? Any ideas? Its author is [Shlomi Noach](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/37086/shlomi-noach), an active StackExchange user.

Comment: As with any code you would use in an environment where you value security you audit it?  i.e. if you are concerned about the security of some data you do not allow code that did not pass your QA/QC process run on it.  And "a lot of people use it" is not necessarily a good reason to argue that a piece of code is safe.

Comment: I think your instincts to question it are good - consider bringing in only what is needed and auditing that.